# How to correctly configure and use WookMark Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wookmark

I'm trying to use Wookmark js to show images on my website, I've followed the official guide but the plugin seems to not work, probably for some inheritance of my CSS theme.
Images simply shows up in a list.

I've uploaded jquery-1.10.2-min, wookmark css and jquery.wookmark.js and followed this page source code [Wookmark](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/masonry/demos/wookmark.html)

How can I fix this problem?
You can see my [website](http://test.theglancy.com/)

Comment: can you be more specific? I don't find any difference between my code and the tutorial.

Comment: is this page up-to-date ? where do you init plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle for example - http://jsfiddle.net/qcsm3/ - its an example from wookmark github.

Firstly, define tile selector.

```
var handler = $('#tiles li');
```

then start plugin

```
handler.wookmark({

    autoResize: true,resized.
    container: $('#main'),
    offset: 5,
    outerOffset: 10,
    itemWidth: 210

});
```